# Can I associate Multiple campaigns to a web to Lead form?

Tags: html, web2lead

I have a single web to lead form, based on the lead's picklist value input i would like to associate that particular lead to a campaign is this possible ?

Comment: For your question, the realistic answer is **YES**.  And if you have any implementation/approach to your requirement, please let us know where you stuck. People are really looking forward to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

Yes, it could be done several ways. You could write JavaScript on the web2lead form to specify a hidden field. You could build a Process Builder to assign a campaign record based on the picklist value, either directly, by Apex Code, or by a Flow. You could write a trigger on Lead to assign the campaign based on the picklist value. Whichever method you prefer is up to you, they're all about the same.